# Initialize viewControllers from its types

Tags: swift, types, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I have a list of view controller types. I want to initialize the corresponding types out of it.

```
struct TabbedViewControllers {
    static var viewControllers: [UIViewController.Type] {
        return [FeedViewController.self,
                SearchViewController.self,
                NotificationViewController.self,
                ProfileViewController.self]
    }
}
```

Here, `FeedViewController`, `SearchViewController`, `NotificationViewController`, `ProfileViewController` are UIViewController types.

I am creating a custom TabBarControllerViewController class where I need to set the viewControllers array from the `TabbedViewControllers.viewControllers` property.

```
class TabBarControllerViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    func setViewControllers() {
        for vc in TabbedViewControllers.viewControllers {
            self.viewControllers?.append(vc)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting compile time error -
`Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'`

How to initialize viewControllers from its types.

Can anyone help.

Comment: I think you can just vc.init

Comment: I already did that but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't pass `Type` of UIViewController to TabBar. You need to pass fully initialized object of `UIViewController` to TabBar for it to work.

You can simply initialize your UIViewController and pass the object

```
struct TabbedViewControllers {
   static var viewControllers: [UIViewController] {
       return [FeedViewController(),
               SearchViewController(),
               NotificationViewController(),
               ProfileViewController()]
   }
}
```

Or if using a storyboard

```
struct TabbedViewControllers {
   static var viewControllers: [UIViewController] {
       return [
          UIStoryboard(name: "FeedViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedViewController"),
          UIStoryboard(name: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController"),
          UIStoryboard(name: "NotificationViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewController"),
          UIStoryboard(name: "ProfileViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
       ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are wrong, we can pass Types. Also I am not using storyboard. I can do it by initializing but I don't want that way.

Comment: There must be some type of mapping or extension written on Type. Otherwise it's not possible to set TabBarController using just Types.